# Node.js remote debug on Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, remote-debugging

I followed this post [Debugging Node.js Azure Web Apps](http://willi.am/blog/2015/07/24/debugging-nodejs-azure-web-apps/) and set my environment accordingly.

It seems like "mysite.azurewebsites.net/server.js/debug" connects to the server and load the scripts but the Websocket connections returns.

```
Overrides.js:17 WebSocket connection to 'ws://mysite/server.js/debug/ws' 
failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500
2016-02-12 15:14:20.147 Overrides.js:27 EventonWebSocketError @ Overrides.js:27
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you can the old method, which use iisnode-inspector.dll. set `debuggerExtensionDll: iisnode-inspector.dll` in `iisnode.yml` for debugging the node.js scripts by iisnode, as the workaround shown at [issue#388](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/388).

And additionally, you can leverage VSO extension on Azure Web Apps, which provides an online editor and cmdlet tool. You can refer to [this thread on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3615e842-a942-46fe-a288-3266ffc715b3/nodejs-cant-access-my-web-site-error-403?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview)

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled WebSockets from the Azure portal? WebSockets are disabled by default and have to be manually enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there might be something wrong with the latest Node Inspector on Azure. Please try the following to go back to the earlier version. In your web.config, set this:

```
<iisnode debuggerExtensionDll="iisnode-inspector.dll" />
```

Also, you can turn off WebSockets with that older version as it doesn't need it.